# How does compareTo() function work in java? Why does it change based on where the variables are positioned?

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

```
int value = b.compareTo(a);
int value = a.compareTo(b);
```

why does I get two different values for each of them? Aren't they the same? How does it work, can anyone explain?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Comment: Why do you excpect the same values? a and b are obviously diferent.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if `a > b` is true, then `b > a` is not true, but `b < a` is true.